# How to set different page properties for the first, even and odd pages using OOXML?

Tags: openxml-sdk, openxml, word-2010

Is there a way, using Open XML SDK, to set different page size, orientation and margins for the first, even an odd pages. I know how to set different headers and footers for the first, even, and odd pages but I can't figure out how to set different first even and odd page properties (size, margin, orientation) .

Regards.

Comment: can you tell me how to add odd and even page header and footer?

Comment: You can create a document with even odd header footer with Microsoft Word then you reflect the document with Open XML SDK productivity tool and you make your customizations. Also this topic can help you http://openxmldeveloper.org/blog/b/openxmldeveloper/archive/2009/04/07/4273.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't.  Those properties are set at the section level, and sectPr elements are attached to specific paragraphs.  They apply to everything in the section (not just odd pages for example).

You can of course set page properties for specific pages, by making a section out of them, but this requires hard coded page breaks / section breaks before and after.